# NextJS Auth0 props type error when wrapping withPageAuthRequired

Tags: typescript, next.js, auth0

I'm currently using Next 13.4 with the page router and Auth0's Next library for authentication. I'm trying to implement page-based Role Based Access Control by wrapping `withPageAuthRequired` like so:

```
type Indexable = { [key: string]: any };

const withClaims = <TProps extends Indexable = Indexable, TParams extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery>(
    opts?: WithPageAuthRequiredOptions<TProps, TParams>,
) =>
    withPageAuthRequired<TProps, TParams>({
        async getServerSideProps(context) { // <-- ERROR HERE
            const hasRole = await userHasRoles(context);

            if (!hasRole)
                return {
                    props: {},
                    redirect: {
                        destination: '/403',
                    },
                };

            if (!opts?.getServerSideProps) return { props: {} };

            return opts.getServerSideProps(context);
        },
    });
```

This logic works but I get the following error:

```
Type '(context: GetServerSidePropsContext<TParams, PreviewData>) => Promise<{ redirect: Redirect; } | { notFound: true; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSideProps<TProps, TParams>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ redirect: Redirect; } | { notFound: true; } | { props: TProps | Promise<TProps>; } | { props: TProps; redirect: { destination: string; }; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<TProps>>'.
    Type '{ redirect: Redirect; } | { notFound: true; } | { props: TProps | Promise<TProps>; } | { props: TProps; redirect: { destination: string; }; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<TProps>'.
      Type '{ props: {}; redirect?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<TProps>'.
        Type '{ props: {}; redirect?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ props: TProps | Promise<TProps>; }'.
          Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'TProps | Promise<TProps>'.ts(2322)
```

I believe this error comes up because `TProps` could be defined as more restrictive than `{}`. For example if I add a line:

`const EMPTY_PROPS: TProps = {};`

I get the error

`'{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TProps', but 'TProps' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Indexable'`

I'm considering a couple of options:

1. Casting `{} as TProps` because the two cases where props is set to `{}` I know the page component will not expect any props from SSR.
2. Adding an argument to `withClaims`: `fallbackProps: TProps` to force the consumer to provide type-safe props to fall back to.

Neither of these are very attractive to me. The first because I don't want to throw away type safety. The second I don't like because it requires consumers of `withClaims` to provide an argument that gets applied, but not used due to the redirect (or an empty object when `getServerSideProps` is not required).

Are there any other solutions I could implement while still conforming to the Auth0 types?